# Finding the exact file names that Cargo puts under `target/*/deps`

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo

I have a crate where if I run `cargo rustc --release -- --emit=llvm-ir`, I get the following files under `target/release/deps`:

```
target/release/deps/
├── chip8_c64-a95cc9a5a3e99697.d
├── chip8_c64-a95cc9a5a3e99697.ll
├── chip8_engine-2a1bf4bc9333b677.d
├── chip8_engine-2a1bf4bc9333b677.ll
├── libchip8_c64-a95cc9a5a3e99697.rlib
├── libchip8_c64-a95cc9a5a3e99697.rmeta
├── libchip8_engine-2a1bf4bc9333b677.rlib
└── libchip8_engine-2a1bf4bc9333b677.rmeta
```

Of course, if I change stuff, the hashes/guids in the file names change.

I would like to find out from the command line / in a Makefile, after running the above command, what these exact file names are. Is there a way to get this information from Cargo?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/json.html#artifact-notifications

Comment: @eggyal: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use that. If I pass just `--json=artifacts` to `cargo rustc`, I only get extra JSON output when there are new files. But to use it from a Makefile, I'd need something stateless, so that even when nothing gets rebuilt, I get the (non-changed) output file names.

Comment: Is the same also true of https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/external-tools.html#artifact-messages ? (Apologies am on mobile so not easy to check).  I would have imagined these should list all artifacts, even if they are already fresh.